# stacking 4 functioncalls on top of each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Long story short, I want to be able to execute 4 functions in a row and making sure that the first is finished before the second function starts etc. How can this be solved in the best way?

Here is the deal. I have 4 different `<select>` fields (stacked next to each other in a row) which is about to be populated with a arbitrary number of `<option>` tags. I have a function called `UpdateList(id)` which works and when I call it, it goes to the database and prints out values in the  in the next  depending on what I have already chosen in previous `<select>`. Now I want to be able to preselect values in this  depending on what I give in the url. For example if I give the below url I want to preselect `1) <option> test` `:2 <option>test2` `:3 <option>test3`
`:4 <option>test4.` Now I assume that these  values exsists in the database.

```
example.com?to=test&tc=test2&te=test3&tet=test4
```

The problem is that when I call

```
UpdateList(t);  
UpdateList(v);
UpdateList(w);
UpdateList(z);
```

The first function isn't finished before the second function starts and hence it doesn't print out any values in the second  with id=v (and hence not the last two as well).

How can I solve this in the best way? I have thought about something like, but it doesn't work.

```
  UpdateList(t); 
    setTimeout(function(){
    UpdateList(v);
    setTimeout(function(){
    UpdateList(w);
    setTimeout(function(){
    UpdateList(z);
    },100);  
    },110);  
    },120);



<select id="u" onchange="UpdateList(this.id);"></select><option><!-PHP rendered options goes here->
<select id="v" onchange="UpdateList(this.id);"></select>!-PHP rendered options goes here->
<select id="w" onchange="UpdateList(this.id);"></select>!-PHP rendered options goes here->
<select id="z" onchange="UpdateList(this.id);"></select>!-PHP rendered options goes here->
```

Sorry if unspecified question =).

Comment: Please provide source for one of your `UpdateList` functions. If they're executing an AJAX request with jQuery, take a look at [promise object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR).

Comment: No, don't use `setTimeout`. Either the task executed by the function is synchronous (then you don't need to do anything), or it is asynchronous (then the function should somehow signal you when it has finished).

Answer (score 1):

Use a promise library such as q https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Here is an excerpt from the q documentation:

On the first pass, promises can mitigate the “Pyramid of Doom”: the situation where code marches to the right faster than it marches forward.

```
step1(function (value1) {
    step2(value1, function(value2) {
        step3(value2, function(value3) {
            step4(value3, function(value4) {
                // Do something with value4
            });
        });
    });
});
```

With a promise library, you can flatten the pyramid.

```
Q.fcall(promisedStep1)
.then(promisedStep2)
.then(promisedStep3)
.then(promisedStep4)
.then(function (value4) {
    // Do something with value4
})
.catch(function (error) {
// Handle any error from all above steps }) .done();
```

Comment: Why recommend another library without knowing the implementation issue?  Especially when the OP specified jQuery and jQuery has some of these capabilities already?